# NVDA screen Reader not able to read dynamic content

Tags: jquery, nvda

I'm working on making a dynamic web application accessible to the visually impaired via screen readers, and I'm running into an annoying problem.When I test with NVDA Reader. Its not able to read dynamically added content.

Code is below:

```
<div id="section" aria-live="polite" role="alert">
    <div id="floatDiv">
        Some Data here
    </div>
    <div id="choices">
        Some data here
    </div>
</div>
```

I will be changing the section data dynamically. But NVDA Reader is not able to read newly added content.
Has anyone ever seen this kind of behavior before?

Comment: That sounds as if the content which NVDA reads is in some kind of cache that isn't updated when content is added or changed dynamically

Answer (score 1):

I added aria-busy="true" to the code and changing that attribute to false when ever I was adding any data to it and after adding data, change to aria-busy = 'true'

```
<div id="section" aria-live="polite" aria-busy="true" role="alert">
    <div id="floatDiv">
        Some Data here
    </div>
    <div id="choices">
        Some data here
    </div>
</div>
```